# Heroku response for API times out when requested from a Blackberry App - but not from cURL

Tags: node.js, curl, heroku, blackberry-10

I am working on an RESTful API in Node.js as a contractor, which is currently being used by a couple of blackberry apps written by other contractors. The stack is very common: Node, Express and Mongoose, running on heroku.

Consider the following API call:

`curl "https://my-app.herokuapp.com/v2/rest/documents/?view=tree&annotate=ratings,accessible"`

When a Blackberry app written in Java makes this call, it works fine every time.

Now consider this one:

`curl "https://my-app.herokuapp.com/v2/rest/documents/?view=tree&annotate=ratings%2Caccessible%2CcontentSize"`

When an Adobe Air Blackberry app makes this call, it often gets an HTTP 503 from Heroku with the Heroku Error code H12, which means that the request timed out. Although, on the BB app it does display "501 Error" when this happens. The logs show no 501s, only a 503.

However, if I make the same call to the server using `curl`, the response is successful, and for a while afterwards it is successful on the same BB app which previously had trouble with it, too. Almost as if the response succeeded, was cached on Heroku's side and then stayed cached for a while (this is speculation).

The main difference is the inclusion of `contentSize` in the `annotate` query-string parameter. But clearly, it isn't slowing it down too much since it seems to work fine when called through `curl`.

Sadly, I do not have access to the source code of either of the BB apps, and the developers are generally quite slow to respond since it is not their only project.

So I was hoping that somebody on SO might have some experience with this kind of a problem and maybe point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is the app in question scaled enough to prevent idling? I ask in particular as the "curl-ing then allows BB to work for a while". Perhaps the timeouts are occurring when BB app is trying to access the idled service? Not sure off the top of my head outside of that, but might be a good place to start looking at least.

Comment: It does idle at times, yes. Interesting idea, but why would a request from curl bring it out of idleness rather than a request from a BB app?

Comment: A fine question. If it really is idle that is the problem I would expect that even if an initial BB request timed out, that subsequent ones would succeed. This would then parallel a curl succeeding, followed by BB succeeding for a time. Do you see that or do only the curl requests allow for some success?

Comment: I hate to say it, but only the curl requests allow for some success. It's very strange indeed. The best explanation I can think of for this is that maybe - and I can't easily confirm this - the blackberry app is caching responses naively, and the second request is assumed to be a failure.

Comment: I could see that. Is there any way to configure the timeout value for BB? Also, working to make your app start up faster may help (if idling is involved anyway), but that's not always an easy/obvious path.

Comment: What I'll do is suggest to the BB devs that they give it a couple of tries if it fails the first or second time with a couple of hundred mills in between each one. I'd be surprised if they weren't already, though. As for improving the startup? Not so easy sadly - I'm part-time on this project, not a lot of time but I'll try. Thanks for the suggestion though, I'll keep it in mind for future things. Cheers for all your thoughts geemus :)

Comment: Sure thing. Wish I had the golden bullet to solve this for you, but afraid BB ecosystem is well beyond my expertise. If you have further questions or anything do let me know, hopefully that helps. You could also just check the scale of the app `heroku ps`. I think it will idle unless "web" processes are scaled to 2 or more, so that may help clarify if this is the issue or not. Some more details related to that here, in case it helps: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#dyno-sleeping

Comment: Aha! Yeah we only have one for this particular instance, so I guess it will remain idle regardless! Thanks again for all your help, you've been generous!

Comment: Sure thing. Yeah, if there is just one dyno it will idle after an hour of inactivity (but would unidle after the first new request). That first request might still take a while though. So sounds like this may in some way be the issue for you (and retries might fix it, or scaling up). Glad to help!